# AWS Lambda destination Lambda not triggering

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

**Background:**

I'm developing a custom AWS github-webhook via Terraform. I'm using AWS API Gateway to trigger an AWS Lambda function that validates the GitHub webhook's sha256 signature from the request header. If the lambda function successfully validates the request, I want a child lambda function to be invoked via the async invocation destination feature provided by Lambda.

**Problem:**

Even though I've configured the async invocation with the target child Lambda function, the child function is not triggered when the parent Lambda function is successful. This is reflected in the fact that the child Lambda function's associated CloudWatch log group is empty.

**Relevant Code:**

Here's the Terraform configuration for the Lambda function destination:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function_event_invoke_config" "lambda" {
  function_name = module.github_webhook.function_name
  destination_config {
    on_success {
      destination = module.lambda.function_arn
    }
  }
}
```

If more code from the module is needed, feel free to ask in the comments. The entire source code for this module is here: https://github.com/marshall7m/terraform-aws-codebuild/tree/master/modules/dynamic-github-source

**Attempts:**

- Made sure both parent/child Lambda functions have permission to create logs within their respective Cloudwatch log group (attached `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policy to both)
- Made sure the parent Lambda function has the correct permission to invoke the child function: `"lambda:InvokeFunction", "lambda:InvokeAsync"`
- Setup async invocation for child lambda function for both success and failure parent Lambda runs (child function still not triggered)
- Add API integration request parameter `{'X-Amz-Invocation-Type': 'Event'} as mentioned in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html
- For every attempt to fix this, I made sure to redeliver the request from the source (github webhook page) and not via the AWS Lambda console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it seems to me that you are invoking parent function synchronously. [Lambda destinations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) are only for **asynchronous** invocations:

> You can also configure Lambda to send an invocation record to another service. Lambda supports the following destinations for **asynchronous invocation**

So you have to execute your parent function asynchronously for your child function to be invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Marcin. To invoke the parent function asynchronously, I added a request parameter with a static 'event' value within the API integration associated with the parent lambda function as mentioned in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html . The child function is still not triggered.

Comment: @Marshallm Have you tried using AWS CLI to confirm that it works or not, without github?

Comment: I tried using the AWS CLI via `aws lambda invoke --function-name payload-validator-anlcAA0MBMI  --invocation-type Event response.json` and the child function is successfully triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the API integration request parameter `{'X-Amz-Invocation-Type': 'Event'} as mentioned in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html did the trick. I initially came to the conclusion that this solution doesn't work based on the fact that a new Cloudwatch log group stream wasn't created when I redelivered the github payload. As it turns out, when I took a closer look at the previous Cloudwatch log stream, I found out that Cloudwatch appends logs for retriggered invocations of the Lambda function to the previous associated Cloudwatch log stream.